# Missing countries from natural earth topojson map?

Tags: topojson

I am missing South Sudan (and Western Sahara) from my natural earth map ([ne_10m_admin_0_countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip)):

[image]

Here is how I am creating my map:

```
? ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('DJI', 'DZA', 'EGY', 'LBY', 'MAR', 'TUN', 'AGO', 'BDI', 'BEN', 'BFA', 'BWA', 'CAF', 'CIV', 'CMR', 'COD', 'COG', 'COM', 'CPV', 'ERI', 'ETH', 'GAB', 'GHA', 'GIN', 'GMB', 'GNB', 'GNQ', 'KEN', 'LBR', 'LSO', 'MDG', 'MLI', 'MOZ', 'MRT', 'MUS', 'MWI', 'NAM', 'NER', 'NGA', 'RWA', 'SDN', 'SEN', 'SLE', 'SOM', 'SSD', 'STP', 'SWZ', 'SYC', 'TCD', 'TGO', 'TZA', 'UGA', 'ZAF', 'ZMB', 'ZWE', 'ESH')" areas.json ne_110m_admin_0_countries/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp

? topojson -o mymmap.json --id-property iso_a3 areas.json
```

I have 'SSD' (South Sudan) and 'ESH' (Western Sahara) in my list of areas to include.

I've tried the following maps:

- ne_110m_admin_0_countries
- ne_110m_admin_0_map_units
- ne_110m_admin_0_sovereignty

...but I still get these missing shapes. On searching mymap.json, I cannot find either 'SSD' or 'ESH'?

Basically, I don't want two white holes in my map, if I can avoid it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSD and ESH don't exist as ADM0_A3 classification in that file. Maybe try ISO_A3 instead?